# Is there a way to create .msg files for Outlook on a Linux based system?

Tags: python, linux, outlook

So my current situation is like that. I got a website running using flask. Based on user input I want to create a already prepared .msg file for Outlook. The part of transmitting user input to flask is already working, so now i only need to create the .msg file. I just can't figure out the way on how to do it. Preferably it should be able to be run on a linux based system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create an EML (MIME) file - Outlook will be happy to show it to the user just like an MSG file. If you want the message to be unsent, don't forget to set the `X-Unsent` MIME header.

Comment: This is perfect! I knew about creating a EML file but i didnt know about the X-Unsent MIME header. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.msg` files as long as you have some form of outlook app at your disposal. Because `.msg` is a propriatery format, the chance of you creating one without some MS tool (like outlook) is very unlikely. If you have outlook, you can download your emails in that format and then use them in your app.

There are plenty of `.msg` readers and converters to `.eml`, but sadly nothing Linux based as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The .msg file is described in depth. So, you are free to compose them on your own. See [Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) for more information.

I have found an open-source library which can be used in C# for generating .msg files - [MsgKit](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit). And I think you can find a similar assembly that can be used in your programming language too.

Finally, you can find third-party libraries for generating .msg file programmatically, see [Aspose](https://docs.aspose.com/display/emailnet/Creating+an+Outlook+Message+%28MSG%29+File).